# how to handle bytes in Wireshark lua script such as 180104000118192021222323 format to --> Message 18010400 0118192021222323

Tags: lua, wireshark

I want to format hex bytes --> 180104000118192021222323 into this form --> Message  18010400  0118192021222323 where
"Message" is a custom string i want to attach before each hex bytes. Technically I have hex dump into

180104000118192021222323
180104000118192021222323
180104000118192021222323

which I want to convert into -->

Message  18010400  0118192021222323
Message  18010400  0118192021222323
Message  18010400  0118192021222323

I don't know how to add the space and how to run in the loop? any help will be highly appreciated since I am new to lua?

Comment: what is 180104000118192021222323 180104000118192021222323 180104000118192021222323? a string?

Comment: Agree with previous comment. Can you post the code you have? Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the hex bytes are coming from or where you want the message printed, but maybe refer to my answers (especially the 2nd one) to a loosely-related question on the Wireshark Q&A site, where I demonstrated how to add some hex bytes for a particular field of interest to the Info column: https://ask.wireshark.org/question/18387/lua-get-hex-value-of-a-field/

In your case, the solution might look a bit more like this:

```
pinfo.cols.info:append("Message " .. tostring(some_field.range:bytes()) .. " ")
```